# How to get the expected output in the description from a given string

Tags: java, regex, string

**[Scoring]: Bot-16 got 2.0 bounty from [Actor - Kill] [Victim: Actor200_(Actor_Local_Minion_200)] [@152133]**

How to format the above string so that I get the following output :

**Player-ID = Bot-16**

**Points = 2.0**

**Action = [Actor-Kill]**

**Victim = Actor200_(Actor_Local_Minion_200)**

**Timestamp = 152133**

Also some lines do not have the victim tag, like in the following String

**[Scoring]: 2 Dev 158744780 got 20.0 bounty from [Actor - Kill] [Ace] [@519382]**

And the output should be

**Player-ID = 2 Dev 158744780**

**Points = 20.0**

**Action = Actor-Kill**

**Victim = Ace**

**Timestamp = 519382**

Comment: if your format doesn't change much, you can use regex to extract details. Something like,  `"[Scoring]: Bot-16 got 2.0 bounty from [Actor - Kill] [Victim: Actor200_(Actor_Local_Minion_200)] [@152133]".match(/(\[Scoring\]:)\s(Bot.*)\s(\[Ac.*])\s(\[.*\])\s(\[@.*\])/)`. This is JS, but should be similar in JAVA as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to deal with this.

Looking at your input strings, I've come up with this regex:

```
\[Scoring\]: (.*) got ([^\s]*) bounty from \[([^\]]*)\] \[(?:Victim: )?([^\]]*)\] \[@([^\]]*)\]
```

DEMO HERE: https://regex101.com/r/e3zuKw/2

So this is the demo program in Java and it's output. I think it will be the solution for you.

Output:

```
**First Input**
Player-ID = Bot-16
Points = 2.0
Action = Actor - Kill
Victim = Actor200_(Actor_Local_Minion_200)
Timestamp = 152133

**Second Input**
Player-ID = 2 Dev 158744780
Points = 20.0
Action = Actor - Kill
Victim = Ace
Timestamp = 519382
```

Code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("**First Input**");
        printInfo("[Scoring]: Bot-16 got 2.0 bounty from [Actor - Kill] [Victim: Actor200_(Actor_Local_Minion_200)] [@152133]");

        System.out.println("\n**Second Input**");
        printInfo("[Scoring]: 2 Dev 158744780 got 20.0 bounty from [Actor - Kill] [Ace] [@519382]");
    }

    public static void printInfo(String line) {
        String pattern = "\\[Scoring\\]: (.*) got ([^\\s]*) bounty from \\[([^\\]]*)\\] \\[(?:Victim: )?([^\\]]*)\\] \\[@([^\\]]*)\\]";

        Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
        Matcher m = r.matcher(line);

        if (m.find()) {
            System.out.println("Player-ID = " + m.group(1));
            System.out.println("Points = " + m.group(2));
            System.out.println("Action = " + m.group(3));
            System.out.println("Victim = " + m.group(4));
            System.out.println("Timestamp = " + m.group(5));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly how i wanted it. Thank you so much. I was working on regex but couldn't exactly get what i wanted. But this is just perfect.